# Determinant of a permutation matrix plus identity

Tags: matrices, determinant, permutation-matrices

> Let $A$ be a permutation matrix. Calculate $\det(I + A)$.

---

I tried with the definition of the determinant but couldn't find it. I also tried to use the decomposition of permutations as products of disjoint cycles.

Comment: What numbers are you getting for the determinants ?

Comment: What makes you think this has a specific answer?  It could be $0$ (*e.g. if $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$*).  It could be $2^n$ (*e.g. if $A=I$*).  It could be many things inbetween.

Comment: As you say you can decompose the permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, so really you just need the answer for the case when $A$ is $n\times n$ and represents an $n$ cycle. The best I can do in that case is that the answer is the product of a certain root of unity times a product of cosines times a power of $2$.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes ! you got it right !
Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reasonable approach. First, consider the case in which $A$ is the size $n$ matrix of a single cycle of length $n$. We find that the associated characteristic polynomial is
$$
\det(A - \lambda I) = (-1)^n(\lambda^n - 1).
$$
To calculate $\det(A + I)$, it suffices to plug in $\lambda = -1$. We find that
$$
\det(A + I) = (-1)^n((-1)^n - 1) = \begin{cases}2 & n \text{ is odd,}\\ 0 & n \text{ is even.}\end{cases}
$$
For the general case, let $A_1,\dots,A_k$ denote the matrices associated with each of the disjoint cycles in the cycle decomposition of $A$. We see that $A$ is similar (permutation similar, in fact) to the block diagonal matrix
$$
PAP^{-1} = \pmatrix{A_1\\ & \ddots \\ && A_k}.
$$
It follows that $\det(A + I) = \det(PAP^{-1} + I) = \det(A_1 + I) \cdots \det(A_k + I)$.

Thus, we reach the following conclusion: suppose that the permutation associated with $A$ can be decomposed into a product of $k$ cycles. If one of those cycles has even length, then $\det(A + I) = 0$. Otherwise, we find that $\det(A + I) = 2^k$.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you ! 
Small extensions for the readers: 
The minimal polynomial of a cycle whose length is n is $X^n-1$. While the minimal polynomial of a permutation is the LCM of the $X^{n_i}-1$ with $n_i$ the length of each cycle in his decomposition.
Plus, in the proof above, the cycle might have a number of cycles with odd lengths inferior to $k$, if we name m the number of cycles with odd lengths, we would have $det(A+I)=2^m$.

Comment: @KevinTran Your second sentence is incorrect: if there are less than $k$ odd cycles (i.e. there is at least one even cycle), then the determinant must be zero

Comment: Yes ! You are right ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For the readers who want more, the question that follows is as the following :
Considering $T_n=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}^{} det(I+P_{\sigma})$, prove that $T_{n+1}=2T_{n}+n(n-1)T_n$ to determine a simple formula for $T_n$